# Tree graph showing the orbits under the Collatz map?

Tags: animation, visualization, trees, demonstrations

[ReverseCollatzPaths](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ReverseCollatzPaths/) is a nice demonstration of a radial tree graph showing the orbits under the Collatz map. However, [Jason Davies](http://www.jasondavies.com/) gives, I think, a nicer [visulalization](https://www.jasondavies.com/collatz-graph/) using Python, with a particularly pleasing radial node-link tree layout and interactivity, which is "smoother" than that available in *Mathematica*. My question is, how can such smooth interpolation between "frames" in, say, a Manipulate be incorporated into *Mathematica*?

Aside: One thing that I'd not noticed before is the *symmetry* of this tree graph about the central node, clearly visible as you change the orbit length one step at a time, which *breaks* when the orbit length is 16. Interested to know the reason for the symmetry breaking (this symmetry is lost if one uses the modified Collatz map, (3n+1)/2 for odd n).